# CentOS: Two Versions of Python and Packages

Tags: python, python-2.7, twisted, multiple-versions

I'm no Python or CentOS (CloudLinux 6.6 + WHM/cPanel) expert, but I'm trying to install an updated version of Python under CentOS with some extra packages and keeping the system version working.

I managet to get Python 2.7 installed by:

```
yum groupinstall -y development
yum install -y zlib-dev openssl-devel sqlite-devel bzip2-devel    
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.6/Python-2.7.6.tgz
tar xzf Python-2.7.6.tgz
cd Python-2.7.6
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
make
sudo make alt install
```

If I run `python` I get `Python 2.6.6` and `python2.7` gives me `Python 2.7.6`. Yum also seems to work fine, so I guess I didn't break the system.

Now, my problem is, I need to get Twistd installed on the Python 2.7, and it needs `zope.interface` also.

How can I install both of them on the Python 2.7 installation at `/usr/local`?

Also, after that if I want to run a setup for a twistd plugin and run it under the python 2.7 how should I do it?

Thank you.

Comment: After your install, does `/usr/local/bin` have `easy_install` or `pip`?  If only the former you shd be able to `/usr/local/bin/easy_install pip`,  Once you have `pip`, `/usr/local/bin/pip install zope.interface` &c should help.  If you don't have `easy_install` see https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools , using `python2.7` where those instructions use just `python`.

Comment: This question is getting older but here is a related StackOverflow Q&A where four different versions of python and pip are installed [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61125258/upgrading-pip-removes-other-pythons-pips/61126915#61126915).  Virtual environments are still the preferred method when using python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use virtualenv for this. Here is the steps that you can follow:

1. install [virtualenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv):

   <strike>sudo yum install virtualenv</strike>

   wget bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py

   python get-pip.py --user

   pip install virtualenv
2. create a virtual env for you app, and precise the python binary you want to use:

   virtualenv -p /usr/local/bin/python2.7 ~/venv
3. Activate it:

   source ~/venv/bin/activate
4. now you are in you virtual env. every python command that you will run will use the python2.7 specified in the command line. Also you can now use [pip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) to install python packages (again, only in your virtual env folder):

   pip install Twisted

Dependencies will be handled automatically.

Note that you may need some dev rpm packages as Twisted needs some C compilation.

Comment: `No package virtualenv available.` :( I guess CloudLinux based on CentOS doesn't have this...

Comment: I suggest that you install pip as indicated here (https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html) if you do not have it, and "sudo pip install virtualenv". then go with the rest of the steps, it should be ok.

Comment: Can you please replace with 1. with: wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py; 
python get-pip.py --no-index --find-links=/local/copies;
python get-pip.py --user; This way other users with CloudLinux/CentOS can benefit easily ;)

Comment: You're welcome. :) Are you sure that you needed the two python get-pip.py commands ? Maybe just "python get-pip.py" is sufficient, or the command with the --user flag only ?

Comment: I guess the one with the --user flag is enough. I started by running the other one, but it ended up on a error, so I tried the user and it worked just fine ;)