# Upgrading `pip` removes other python's pips

Tags: python, linux, pip

On a CentOS 7 system, I have multiple versions of Python installed, each with their own version of `pip`:

```
# head -n1 /usr/local/bin/pip3.*
==> /usr/local/bin/pip3.6 <==
#!/usr/bin/python3

==> /usr/local/bin/pip3.7 <==
#!/usr/local/bin/python3.7

==> /usr/local/bin/pip3.8 <==
#!/usr/local/bin/python3.8
```

When I ask `pip3.8` to upgrade itself, it removes the installed `pip3.7`:

```
# pip3.8 install --upgrade pip
Collecting pip
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/54/0c/d01aa759fdc501a58f431eb594a17495f15b88da142ce14b5845662c13f3/pip-20.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 19.2.3
    Uninstalling pip-19.2.3:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-19.2.3
Successfully installed pip-20.0.2


# head -n1 /usr/local/bin/pip3.*
==> /usr/local/bin/pip3.6 <==
#!/usr/bin/python3

==> /usr/local/bin/pip3.8 <==
#!/usr/local/bin/python3.8
```

Why is it doing this, and how can I prevent it?

**UPDATES**:

- The lib paths are different for the two installations, as shown here:

```
# python3.7 -c 'import sys; print(sys.path)'
['', '/usr/local/lib/python37.zip', '/usr/local/lib/python3.7', '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages']
# python3.8 -c 'import sys; print(sys.path)'
['', '/usr/local/lib/python38.zip', '/usr/local/lib/python3.8', '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages']
```

- It is not bidirectional - upgrading `pip3.7` does not remove `pip3.8`.
- I believe the *library* gets upgraded correctly and leaves the version 3.7 library in place, it's just the shell wrapper script that's deleted.  Here's after the `pip3.8` upgrade:

```
# python3.7 -m pip --version
pip 20.0.2 from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
# python3.8 -m pip --version
pip 20.0.2 from /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)
# pip3.7 --version
bash: pip3.7: command not found
# pip3.8 --version
pip 20.0.2 from /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)
```

- Doing `pip3.7 install --upgrade pip` does not remove `/usr/local/bin/pip3.6`, so it's not the case that it always removes previous versions.
- For full reproducibility, and to show that I'm starting with a fairly pristine system, here's a Gist containing my Dockerfile text: https://gist.github.com/kenahoo/a1104f9cb84694fbd5ec9d6d560a885e .  It fails on the `RUN pip3.7 install setuptools numpy pandas` line because `pip3.7` has gone missing.
- It doesn't matter whether I upgrade using `python3.8 -m pip install --upgrade pip` or `pip3.8 install --upgrade pip`, both of them end up removing the `/usr/local/bin/pip3.7` wrapper script.

Comment: Were your 3.7 and 3.8 installs pointed at the same package dir?

Comment: is this bidirectional, i.e. upgrading `pip3.7` removes `pip3.8`?

Comment: @jordanm and norok2 - thanks, I've addressed those questions in updates to the question.

Comment: Can you install python 3.4 and see if that gets removed by pip3.7 upgrade? It may be removing earlier version entry points. Not sure if that is the expected behavior.

Comment: Using virtual environments will likely help this since only the packaged pip will be changed.

Comment: @norok2 pip apparently doesn't support python3.4 anymore, but in a similar test, I confirmed that doing `pip3.7 install --upgrade pip` does not remove `/usr/local/bin/pip3.6`.

Comment: @lwileczek that's true, but I'm trying to create a Docker image where several versions of python and their corresponding `pip`s are coinstalled harmoniously system-wide.

Comment: What I find strange is that `pip` seems to be at the same version. So there is something in your environment or in the code that gets triggered for 3.8 and not for the other versions.

Comment: Maybe not a solution to your one specific issue, but... I would advise against ever using any the `pip`, `pip3`, `pipX.Y` scripts. It is always better and safer to use the explicit way of calling _pip_'s executable module for a specific Python interpreter instead, for example: `path/to/pythonX.Y -m pip somecommand ...` -- https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/

Comment: @sinoroc that's not really relevant, as long as the wrapper script has the proper shebang line (see the code block at the top of my post), the two are exactly equivalent.

Comment: @Ken Yes, I know it's not a solution per-se. But this issue proves the point that the `pip` scripts are a bit fragile. Calling `path/to/pythonX.Y -m pip` is always a safer bet. As to why it happens, I guess I would look into the versions of _pip_  that are bundled with the Python. Maybe there is an issue in some _pip_ versions so that it cleans up a bit too much (i.e. `pip` scripts for other versions) when it's being uninstalled (as part of the upgrade).

Comment: @Ken Maybe you could find the _metadata_ for _pip_ on a fresh install of Python 3.8. For example it could be a file such as `/path/to/python3.8/site-packages/pip-20.0.2.dist-info/entry_points.txt` and look if there is a `pip3.7` entry in there. For example, right now in front of me I have this file open for a _pip 20.0.2_ in a Python 3.6 environment but it has an entry for `pip3.8`, which doesn't make sense, but it's there so it would delete a potential `pip3.8` instead of `pip3.6` if I were to uninstall it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe I found the issue.

In short, the `pipX.Y` console script is set to the version of the Python interpreter used to build the *pip*'s wheel, instead of the version of the Python interpreter used to install it.

- https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8010

For example take any *pip* installed in any *Python* that is *not 3.8* (in my case it's Python 3.6) and use it to download `pip` itself:

```
$ /path/to/pythonX.Y -m pip download pip
```

This should give you a *wheel* file for example `pip-20.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl`, now unzip it:

```
$ /path/to/pythonX.Y -m zipfile -e pip-20.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl .
```

Now look at the content of `pip-20.0.2.dist-info/entry_points.txt`:

```
$ cat pip-20.0.2.dist-info/entry_points.txt 
[console_scripts]
pip = pip._internal.cli.main:main
pip3 = pip._internal.cli.main:main
pip3.8 = pip._internal.cli.main:main
```

So there is an entry for a console script `pip3.8` even though I have Python 3.6. This is obviously wrong. And for example if I indeed had an actual `pip3.8` script then this file would be deleted when uninstalling the *pip* associated with the Python 3.6, for example to upgrade it.

The root of the issue can be seen here for example:

- https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/19.2.3/setup.py#L76

```
    entry_points={
        "console_scripts": [
            "pip=pip._internal:main",
            "pip%s=pip._internal:main" % sys.version_info[:1],
            "pip%s.%s=pip._internal:main" % sys.version_info[:2],
        ],
    },
```

This line `pip%s.%s=pip._internal:main" % sys.version_info[:2]` gets actually written down definitely when building the *wheel*, and I assume the *wheel* we downloaded earlier was built with *Python 3.8*.

---

That [bug](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8010) is (at least partially) known to *pip*'s maintainers, and not sure it will get fixed (probably not worth it).

Anyway, one should always use the explicit `/path/to/pythonX.Y -m pip` instead. The `pip*` scripts are just shortcuts that are here for convenience. They are somewhat useful from an interactive command line to save some keystrokes and be able to work faster. But in a file, anything from documentation, to *shell* scripts, or *Dockerfiles*, I am the opinion that one should always use the explicit expanded versions. For example I always write `rm --recursive` instead of `rm -r`, etc.

Additionally in the one particular case of *Python*'s *pip*, it makes sense no matter what:

- https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/

Comment: That does indeed look like the issue.  It seems to not be fixed in pip v20 either: https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/20.0.2/setup.py#L79

Comment: Actually I'm still a little confused - if installing pip 3.8 removes `pip3.7`, wouldn't we expect to see an entry for `pip3.7` in the 3.8 `entry_points.txt` file, not the other way around?  What list of files does pip actually use when deciding stuff to uninstall, anyway?

Comment: That's exactly what I said. But most likely the _pip_ version you tried to upgrade **from** came from a wheel that was built with a different interpreter. So probably in your case, the _pip_ that comes originally with _Python 3.8_ came from a wheel that had been built with _Python 3.7_. It could well be that you somehow have the right `pip3.8` script, but the wrong entry in the `entry_points.txt`, and most likely it is this file that is used when uninstalling _pip_ (right before the upgrade), and so it deletes the wrong `pipX.Y` script. Or maybe I just confused myself. I'd have to look closer.

Comment: Aha, you're correct.  My initial `entry_points.txt` for pip in python 3.8 has an entry for `pip3.7 = pip._internal:main`.  So I guess I'd consider this a pip packaging bug, and I can submit that to the pip people.  I'll probably work around it by fixing up that file and then perform the upgrade as usual.

Comment: I already opened a ticket: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8010

Comment: It's a known bug (at least partially known), and not sure it will get fixed (probably not worth it). As I said earlier, always use the explicit `/path/to/pythonX.Y -m pip` instead. The `pip*` scripts are just shortcuts that are here for convenience. They are somewhat useful from an interactive command line to save some keystrokes and be able to work faster. But in a file, anything from documentation, to _shell_ scripts, or _Dockerfiles_, I am the opinion that one should always use the explicit expanded versions. For example I always write `rm --recursive` instead of `rm -r`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

## Update

You can use `pip`'s `target` command to tell pip where it is allowed to look for pip and do an update.

```
$ pip3.8 install --upgrade --target /usr/local/lib/python3./site-packages/ pip
```

To upgrade just pip3.8 which will leave pip 3.7 intact.

When I ran

```
...

RUN pip3.5 install --upgrade --target /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ pip
RUN pip3.6 install --upgrade --target /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ pip
RUN pip3.7 install --upgrade --target /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ pip
RUN pip3.8 install --upgrade --target /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ pip

...
```

pip was still in the site-packages for python3.5/3.6 but pip3.5 & 3.6 did **not** show up in `/usr/local/bin`.  So to install packages *globally* to python3.5/3.6 one would have to use `python3.5 -m pip install <package>`

This is because `pip3.5` and `pip3.6` should be stored in `/usr/bin` not `/usr/local/bin`. You can use

```
...

RUN pip3.5 install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3.6 install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3.7 install --upgrade --target /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ pip
RUN pip3.8 install --upgrade --target /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ pip

...
```

And pip3.5-8 will all exist and work.  It is still advisable to use virtual environments with python.

#### Warning

Pip seems to be issuing a warning that is caused by calling pip directly.  The warning suggestions calling pip as a python module moving forward `python -m pip <command>`

```
[root@93e6e7373eff /]# pip3.8 -V
WARNING: pip is being invoked by an old script wrapper. This will fail in a future version of pip.
Please see https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599 for advice on fixing the underlying issue.
To avoid this problem you can invoke Python with '-m pip' instead of running pip directly.
pip 20.0.2 from /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)

[root@93e6e7373eff /]# pip3.7 -V
WARNING: pip is being invoked by an old script wrapper. This will fail in a future version of pip.
Please see https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599 for advice on fixing the underlying issue.
To avoid this problem you can invoke Python with '-m pip' instead of running pip directly.
pip 20.0.2 from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)

[root@93e6e7373eff /]# pip3.6 -V
pip 20.0.2 from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)

[root@93e6e7373eff /]# pip3.5 -V
pip 20.0.2 from /usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip (python 3.5)
```

---

#### Workaround

I was able to get it all to work by changing the order in which you install.  Since the only issue seems to be that pip3.8 looks for older versions and deletes them, I installed and upgraded before anything else. I just built this on my laptop and it ran (lol it worked on my machine).

```
# -*- dockerfile -*-
FROM centos:7.7.1908
RUN yum update -y
RUN yum install -y epel-release
RUN yum install -y https://centos7.iuscommunity.org/ius-release.rpm

RUN yum install -y python35u python35u-pip
RUN yum install -y python36u python36u-pip

RUN yum install -y gcc gcc-c++
RUN yum install -y make openssl-devel bzip2-devel libffi-devel

# Python3.8 is not currently available from RHEL, EPEL, or IUS repos so download and compile it
ARG PY38_VERSION=3.8.2
RUN cd /usr/src && curl https://www.python.org/ftp/python/${PY38_VERSION}/Python-${PY38_VERSION}.tgz | tar -xz &&\
  cd Python-${PY38_VERSION} && ./configure --enable-optimizations && make -j4 altinstall &&\
  rm -rf /usr/src/Python-${PY38_VERSION}

RUN pip3.8 install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3.8 install setuptools numpy pandas

# Python3.7 is not currently available from RHEL, EPEL, or IUS repos so download and compile it
RUN yum install -y gcc openssl-devel bzip2-devel libffi-devel make sqlite-devel
ARG PY37_VERSION=3.7.6
RUN cd /usr/src && curl https://www.python.org/ftp/python/${PY37_VERSION}/Python-${PY37_VERSION}.tgz | tar -xz &&\
  cd Python-${PY37_VERSION} && ./configure --enable-optimizations && make -j4 altinstall &&\
  rm -rf /usr/src/Python-${PY37_VERSION}

RUN pip3.7 install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3.7 install setuptools numpy pandas

RUN pip3.5 install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3.5 install setuptools numpy pandas
RUN pip3.6 install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3.6 install setuptools numpy pandas


RUN yum install -y python35u-devel python36u-devel python37u-devel python38u-devel


CMD /bin/bash
```

outputs from console:

```sh
[root@e3b166a8b479 /]# python3.7 -m pip -V     
pip 20.0.2 from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
[root@e3b166a8b479 /]# python3.6 -m pip -V
pip 20.0.2 from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)
[root@e3b166a8b479 /]# python3.8 -m pip -V
pip 20.0.2 from /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)
[root@e3b166a8b479 /]# ls /usr/local/bin | grep pip
pip
pip3
pip3.6
pip3.7
pip3.8
```

Comment: Thanks for all this research.  I did notice that pip 3.5 and 3.6 were installed in `/usr/bin` and not `/usr/local/bin`, presumably because they were from vendor RPMs and not source.

Comment: It looks like when I upgrade pip 3.8 using `pip3.8 install --upgrade --target /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ pip` though, the `pip3.8` wrapper is left outdated, and complains saying `WARNING: pip is being invoked by an old script wrapper`.

Comment: ```[root@93e6e7373eff /]# pip3.8 -V
WARNING: pip is being invoked by an old script wrapper. This will fail in a future version of pip.
Please see https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599 for advice on fixing the underlying issue.
To avoid this problem you can invoke Python with '-m pip' instead of running pip directly.
pip 20.0.2 from /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)```  That error seems to be from calling pip directly. Everything should work.  Run the container and poke around to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

I force re-installed the original python3's pip and then I got back the old version in /usr/local/bin/

```
python3 -m pip install --force-reinstall pip
```